# I can't deploy app to the iPod touch due to SDK issue

Tags: ios, ios4

I have iOS SDK 4.3. My iPod touch iOS version is 5.0.1. I deployed my app to iPod touch and I got the message:

```
The version of iOS on “Denz’s iPod” does not match any of the versions of iOS
supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore
the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version
of the iOS SDK; which is available here.

OS Installed on iPod
5.0.1 (9A405)

Xcode Supported iOS Versions
Latest
4.3
4.2
4.1
4.0.2
4.0.1
4.0
3.0
```

I don't want to upgrade my Xcode or install iOS 4.3 on iPod touch. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issues.

I synced my ipod with another mac2 (xcode with ios sdk 5), then I installed my app on the ipod. After this I unplug my ipod from mac2. Then I plug in my ipod to the mac1 (xcode with ios sdk 4.3). Please don't sync an ipod with itunes. Now I can install app from mac1.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a new version of Xcode which supports 5.0 to debug and test on this device. If you don't want to remove the version of xcode you have installed, you can create a Lion VM using Parallels or VMWare and install the new version of Xcode on that.